# Unable to find IIS response logs for php calls

Tags: php, iis, logging, http-status-code

I'm having trouble finding IIS logs for non-erroring calls to php files.

I've recently been given ownership of an IIS 7.5 server that runs php.  While digging through logs, I can't find any records of any regular php calls being made.

Here's the headers for a sample basic request I make

```
curl -v https://my.site.com/filename.php
...
> GET /filename.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: my.site.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 16:04:01 GMT
< Content-Length: 92
```

I would expect an entry in the IIS logs along the lines of (simplified)

[timestamp] - 200 [response time] - filename.php

Yet there's nothing in the IIS logs for this request.
I've looked in:

1. C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1
2. \%systemroot%\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR
3. C:\Windows\Temp\PHP54_errors.log

I'm not interested in anything from within php.  I just want an entry in the IIS log with tiemstamp, file/path, response code, response time etc.

I've searched fairly extensively, but as soon as I search php and logs, I get nothing but how to send something within php to the error logs, which isn't what I'm looking for.  I don't care what's happening inside php, I only care what IIS is pumping out in the end.  It's as if once a php extension is seen, IIS hands over to the php handler and then says "screw this I'm done".

I'm more familiar with linux platforms, so apologies in advance if my windows config is rusty.